# Buttons on iphone App screen is unresponsive after invocation of the mail ui and returning back to the app after send or cancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an ios iphone app. The app has a main window xib consisting of the tab bar and a view area.
There is another xib called subscribe update which consists of a button, users can click the button and send email. This button pops up the email window.
In the app delegate the subscribe update xib is loaded. The subscribe update is added as a subview of the window rootViewController view
When users click the subscribe update button the mail window pops up. After sending the mail or canceling the system returns to the app. When it returns we find that only the subscribe update button is clickable all other buttons on the main screen are not clickable. The subscribe update button shifts its position to top left corner. Screen shots attached.

[App screen. Shows the subscribe update button bottom middle](http://www.softanalytics.in/stackimages/IMG_0031.jpg)

[Email pop up screen](http://www.softanalytics.in/stackimages/IMG_0032.jpg)

[Screen after cancelling and deleting the draft in the email pop up](http://www.softanalytics.in/stackimages/IMG_0033.jpg)

Only subscribe update button is clickable.

```
       (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
       {
        
        self.sharedOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue new] 
        autorelease];
        
    
        SubscribeUpdate *subUpdateCont1 = [[SubscribeUpdate alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"SubscribeUpdate" bundle:nil];
        self.subscribeUpdateController = subUpdateCont1;
        //self.subscribeUpdateController.view.hidden = YES;
        [subUpdateCont1 release];
        
        SubscribeUpdate *subUpdateCont2 = [[SubscribeUpdate alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"SubscribeUpdate" bundle:nil];
        self.subscribeUpdateControllerVideo = subUpdateCont2;
        [subUpdateCont2 release];
    
        // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of 
        the 
        window
        window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        
        [window.rootViewController.view 
         addSubview:subscribeUpdateController.view];
        
        
        CGRect newFrame = subscribeUpdateController.view.frame;
        CGRect newFrameRoot = window.rootViewController.view.frame;
        CGRect newFrameTabBar = tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
        
        
        NSLog(@"root frame x = %d ",(int)newFrameRoot.origin.x);
        NSLog(@"root frame y = %d ",(int)newFrameRoot.origin.y);
        NSLog(@"root frame width = %d ", 
        (int)newFrameRoot.size.width);
        NSLog(@"root frame height = %d ", 
        (int)newFrameRoot.size.height);
        
        NSLog(@"frame x = %d ",(int)newFrame.origin.x);
        NSLog(@"frame y = %d ",(int)newFrame.origin.y);
        NSLog(@"frame width = %d ",(int)newFrame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"frame height = %d ",(int)newFrame.size.height);
        
        NSLog(@"tabbar x = %d ",(int)newFrameTabBar.origin.x);
        NSLog(@"tabbar y = %d ",(int)newFrameTabBar.origin.y);
        NSLog(@"tabbar width = %d ",(int)newFrameTabBar.size.width);
        NSLog(@"tabbar height = %d ", 
        (int)newFrameTabBar.size.height);
        
        
        newFrame.origin.x = newFrameRoot.size.width/2 - 
        newFrame.size.width/2;
        newFrame.origin.y = newFrameRoot.size.height - 
        newFrame.size.height- 
        newFrameTabBar.size.height-10;
        //newFrame.size.width = newFrameRoot.size.width;
        //newFrame.size.width = 200;
        //newFrame.size.height = 200;
        [[subscribeUpdateController view] setHidden:NO];
    
        [subscribeUpdateController.view setFrame:newFrame];
    
        //subscribeUpdateController.view.hidden = YES;
        //subscribeUpdateController.view.alpha = 1;
    
    
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
        setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    
        
        // Place the imageviews on the navigation bar
            //  [window addSubview:imageView];
        //[window addSubview:titleImage];
        if (self.swingFullscreen == nil)
        {
            UINavigationController *navController = 
        [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
            self.swingFullscreen = [navController.viewControllers 
         objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] 
        application:application
                                        
         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
        
         }
    
    
        //In subscribeupdate.m
    
        (IBAction)SendUpdateEmail:(id)sender {
        [self sendEmail:emailAddress subject:updateEmailSubject 
         body:updateEmailBody];
         }
    
           -(void)sendEmail: (NSString *)to subject 
        (NSString*)subject 
         body:(NSString *)body {
           MFMailComposeViewController *composer = 
         [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject: to]];
        [composer setSubject:subject];
        [composer setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
        composer.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        
        GolfCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GolfCoachAppDelegate *) 
         . 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == YES) {
            [self presentViewController:composer animated:true 
           completion:nil];
        }
        [composer release];
         }
    
    
        -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController 
        *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
        error: 
         (NSError *)error {
        
        switch (result) {
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                //Email sent
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                //Email saved
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                //Handle cancelling of the email
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                //Handle failure to send.
                break;
            default:
                //A failure occurred while completing the email
                break;
        }
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

I have tried reordering the views specially the subscribe update view.
Nothing happened.
I have tried hiding the subscribe update view after mail pop up, and in that case the buttons on the main screen start working.